# Jenkins push changes to git

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm making a pipeline that updates some software version numbers in an XML file and push's them back to git \ bitbucket.

I'm pulling the repository down with

```
checkout([
  $class: 'GitSCM'
  extensions: scm.extensions + [
  [
    $class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
    relativeTargetDir: 'sw'
  ],
  ],
  userRemoteConfigs: [[
    credentialsId: env.GIT_CREDS,
    url: env.GIT_REPO
  ]]
  ...
])
```

before using sh commands to create a ticket in Jira and create a branch based of the ticket number. My issue is I can't get it to push back to the repo after I've made my changes. My main issue is injecting the git credentials and the env.GIT_CREDS are just the Credentials ID as a text string, which is handled behind the scenes by the checkout command plugin so I can't even do the 'bad' thing and write a local id_rsa file inside the workspace

My bash script to update the code base is similar to

```
cd sw

git checkout -b $1

# changes made have been removed

git add --all 

git commit -m "Updated software versions $2.$3.$4"

git push --set-upstream origin $1
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use the snippet creator with the `withCredentials`. It gave me the syntax for  `withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(...)])`. However, I'm now trying to work out how to keep a secret for multiple steps but that's out of scope for this question.